# WooCommerce get product id and price in function.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to fetch the product id and price in functions.php, so i can use that price in my hooks right now i am using this code and

i am getting

```
    ID=0(id is like 99, 1733 etc)
    price = Free(but default price is something else)

  $product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID()) ;
  echo $prices = $product->get_price_html();
  echo $price1= $product->id;
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: if you echo get_the_ID() do you get the desired id?

Comment: No i am not getting the id..it's returning 0(zero) instead of the id

Comment: I think that you can't have a kind of generic function in `functions.php` to fetch **`product id`** and **`price`** into your WooCommerce hooks, because it depends of this woocommerce hooks you want to use and on product type too. It will be much more appropriate, that you will include in your question what hooks you want to use and on which kind of products.   Is the hook you want to use inside or outside the loop, on individual product pages, on cart, on checkout, on shop, on archive pages… **Your question is just too broad**

Comment: i want to pass product id & price in cart using custom hooks in my functions.php...

Answer (score 3):

Try this code -

```
<?php 
  global $product;
  $product_id=$product->id;
  echo $product_id;
  $price=$product->get_price_html();
  echo $price; ?>
```

Comment: I have used your code but getting this error  Call to a member function get_price_html() on null

Comment: $product is a string before running certain product page hooks. You cannot run the function get_price() on a string, only on the object, which cannot be done in functions.php without hooking into an woocommerce hook